# Representing a graph (adjacency list) with HashMap[Int, Vector[Int]] (Scala)?

Tags: scala, graph, vector, adjacency-list

I was wondering how (if possible) I can go about making an adjacency list representation of a (mutable) graph via `HashMap[Int, Vector[Int]]`. `HashMap` would be mutable of course.

Currently I have it set as `HashMap[Int, ArrayBuffer[Int]]`, but the fact that I can change each cell in the ArrayBuffer makes me uncomfortable, even though I'm fairly certain I'm not doing that. I would use a `ListBuffer[Int]` but I would like fast random access to neighbors due to my need to do fast random  walks on the graphs. A `Vector[Int]` would solve this problem, but is there anyway to do this?

To my knowledge (tried this in the REPL), this won't work:

```
scala> val x = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Vector[Int]]
x: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Vector[Int]] = Map()

scala> x(3) = Vector(1)

scala> x(3) += 4 // DOES NOT WORK
```

I need to be able to both append to it at any time and also access any element within it randomly (given the index). Is this possible?

Thanks!
-kstruct

Comment: You know about scala-graph? http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-graph/wiki

Comment: Yep - this project is mostly to get myself more familiar with Scala, and for what I'm using this for I only need a rudimentary graph class, nothing too fancy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Vector:

```
x += 3 -> (x(3) :+ 4)  //x.type = Map(3 -> Vector(1, 4))
```

You might notice that this will fail if there's no existing key, so you might like to set up your map as

```
val x = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Vector[Int]] withDefaultValue Vector.empty
```