# Scala not found: value mutable

Tags: scala

I am trying to represent a graph's adjacency list in Scala.

Therefore, I looked at this [Representing a graph (adjacency list) with HashMap[Int, Vector[Int]] (Scala)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358265/representing-a-graph-adjacency-list-with-hashmapint-vectorint-scala) and I tried to represent it as such:

```
val a = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Vector[Pair[Int, Int]]] withDefaultValue Vector.empty
```

I have imported the following:

```
import collection.mutable._
```

However, I still get this error:

```
error: not found: value mutable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've imported everything from `scala.collection.mutable` so you can simply write:

```
 val a = new HashMap[Int, Vector[Pair[Int, Int]]] withDefaultValue Vector.empty
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import collection.mutable._
```

This imports the values and types *inside* `mutable`, but not the symbol `mutable` itself. So you either have

```
import collection.mutable._
val a = new HashMap(...)
```

or

```
import collection.mutable
val a = new mutable.HashMap(...)
```

The latter is usually preferred (for example suggested by IntelliJ) because you can better see that `HashMap` is mutable.